# Django Rest Framework doesn't correctly changes requests text to json

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I got below code:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.status import HTTP_200_OK, HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND


@csrf_exempt
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def login(request):
    print(request.data)
    username = request.data.get("username")
    password = request.data.get("password")
    if username is None or password is None:
        return Response({"error": "Please provide both username and password"}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if not user:
        return Response({"error": "Invalid Credentials"}, status=HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    return Response({"token": token.key}, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

When I am sending below request at http://localhost:80/api/user/login

```
{
   "password":"#%RFzv@2BLYM&#jNh6o@46*74f38SV4q",
   "username":"kamil1234"
}
```

[Request pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdH5P.png)

I am getting as a `request.data` below values:

```
<QueryDict: {'_content_type': ['application/json'], '_content': ['{\r\n   "password":"#%RFzv@2BLYM&#jNh6o@46*74f38SV4q",\r\n   "username":"kamil1234",\r\n}']}>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong in here. Since when I use curl everything works correctly.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:80/api/user/login' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "password": "#%RFzv@2BLYM&#jNh6o@46*74f38SV4q",
    "username": "kamil1234"
}'
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: How are you sending the request that is not working? A simple request on the browser will not work, since you also need to specify the post data

Comment: I pretty much go to http://localhost/api/user/login and use it there. But the same problem I got when I am trying to send it over python.requests and with usage of json

Comment: do you want to return the token?

Comment: @JoshuaEdward yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to settings the default parsers for rest-framework.

This will help: [Parsers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/)